# Change text in givewp WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code snippet to change the text in a WordPress donation form using the plugin GiveWP. The code is adapted from [here](https://github.com/impress-org/givewp-snippet-library/blob/master/translation-snippets/change-text-locally-per-form.php). It is important that this code snippet only changes the text on one donation form (with id `590` in this case).

```
add_action( 'give_pre_form_output', function( $form_id ) {
    if ( $form_id == 590 ) {
        add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translations, $text, $domain) {
            if ( $domain == 'give' && $text == 'Secure Donation' ) {
                return __( 'Secure Payment', 'give' );
            }
            return $translations;
        }, 10, 3);
    }
});
```

The code works as expected, except for the receipt section of the form (i.e. after the user has submitted the payment), where the text remains unchanged. If I remove the wrapping function that checks for `$form_id` the text is changed everywhere, but this would affect other donation forms that I don't want to change.

Is there a way to change the text on the payment receipt section of the form on a per-form basis?

Comment: Unless someone here is overly familiar with the GiveWP plugin, I doubt you'll get help. I would ask the plugin developer if there is an action hook for the receipt section as well.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor. I've raised an issue [here](https://github.com/impress-org/givewp-snippet-library/issues/138) too.